# A topology question about compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact set. Let $f: K \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous and injective function. Then we must have that $f^{-1} : f(K) \to K$ is  continuous.

### My Attempt

Take $F \subseteq K$ closed set. Since $K$ is compact, then $K$ is closed and bounded. Hence, $F$ must be bounded. Since it is closed, then $F$ is compact. By continuity of $f$, we must have that $f(F)$ is compact. Hence, $f(F)$ is closed. By injectivity of $f$, we have that $(f^{-1})^{-1} (F) = f(F) \subseteq f(K) $. Hence, $f^{-1}$ is continuous as desired.

Is this a correct solution? Can we still have this result if $K$ is not compact? I was thinking maybe $f: [0, 2 \pi) \to R^2 $ . But I cant show that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Can someone help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is actually equivalent to showing that the image of a closed set is indeed closed, which is exactly what you have done. Indeed, you only need the injectivity of $f$ to show that $f^{-1}:f(K)\rightarrow K$ is actually defined. 
Showing that the inverse of a function is continuous is equivalent to showing that the function is an open mapping, or a closed map, that is that it sends open sets to open sets, or closed sets to closed sets, which you have actually proved. As far as your second question, you haven't specified a function, do you have one in mind?

Comment: $f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x ) $ ? But how can i show that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous?

Comment: Well from the above discussion and your proof, what does this boil down to showing? Try showing that this function is not an open map. What is the image of $f$? - the unit circle. Can you find an open set in $[0,2\pi)$ that is not sent to an open set in $f[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: $(0,2 \pi)$ is open and is sent to the unit circle without the origen, which is not open. is this correcT?

Comment: $(0,2\pi)$ is sent to the unit circle without the point $(1,0)$. Are you sure this is not open? Remember that you are working with the induced subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is open if its complement in $S^1$ is closed, and its complement in $S^1$ is $\{(1,0)\}$ which is closed. So it is actually open. This thread might be of interest to you : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108853/0-1-to-mathbbr2-injective-continuous-not-a-homeomorphism-on-the-image

Comment: Just keep in mind that the result you proved DOES depend extensively on the compactness of the domain, because continuous functions send compact sets to compact sets. In general continuous functions do NOT send closed sets to closed sets, but a function $f:K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ compact do have this property. So you should expect that that result doesn't hold with $K$ not compact, and if you think your function is a counterxample, then you most show closed sets do not get sent to closed sets. (or open-> open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $[0,\pi)$ which is open in $[0,2\pi)$ ($[0,2\pi)$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ since it is not closed) with $f:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,\enspace f(x)=(cos(x),sin(x))$ as you suggest. Note that $f[0,2\pi)=S^1$, the unit circle. If $f^{-1}:S^1\rightarrow [0,2\pi)$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S^1$ (equipped with the subspace topology) for all $U\subset [0,2\pi)$ open. Equivalently, $f:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow S^1$ is an [open map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_map).

Let $U=[0,\pi)$ then $U$ is open in $[0,2\pi)$. Suppose $f(U)$ is open. since $p:=(1,0)=f(0)\in f(U)$, there must exist $r>0$ such that $B_r(p)\cap S^1\subset f(U)$.

Choose $\pi>\epsilon>0$ such that $(1-\cos(\epsilon))<r^2/2$. Consider the point $x=2\pi-\epsilon\in [0,2\pi)$. Since $f$ is surjective onto $S^1$, $f(x)\in S^1$. I claim that $f(x)\in B_r(p)\cap S^1$. If this is true then we have arrived at a contradiction since then $f(x)\in B_r(p)\cap S^1\subset f(U)$ and $f(x)\notin f(U)$ since $x\in U$ and $f$ is injective.

We have:
\begin{align*}
||p-f(x)||&=||(1,0)-(\cos(2\pi-\epsilon),\sin(2\pi-\epsilon)||\\
          &=||(1-\cos(2\pi-\epsilon), -\sin(2\pi-\epsilon))||\\
          &=\sqrt{(1-\cos(2\pi-\epsilon))^2+\sin(2\pi-\epsilon)^2}\\     
          &=\sqrt{2(1-\cos(2\pi-\epsilon))}<r    
\end{align*}

Thus $f(x)\in B_r(p)\cap S^1$, and so we have reached a contradiction. In particular $f(U)$ is not open in $S^1$ where $U=[0,\pi)$, open in $[0,2\pi)$.

**Remark**
This proves that the statement of the proposition fails in the case we remove the requirement that the domain be compact. Perhaps a more interesting question to ask is does it hold if the domain is closed but not compact?

In regards to the first question, your proof looks good, as I have mentioned in the comments on the OP.